# How to convert 1000+ pdfs to images using multithreading in python as it is taking too long when handles sequentially

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

```
def convertToImage(files):
    for file in files:
    #print(file)
        images = convert_from_path(file,500,strict=False)
        for i, image in enumerate(images):
            fileName = file.split(".")
            fileName = fileName[0]
            #print(fileName)
            fname = str(fileName) + "Image_" + str(i) + ".jpg"
            #print(fname)
            image.save(fname, "JPEG")
            if i == 0:
                imageList.append(fname)
            break
    return imageList
def main():
    files = (glob.glob(r"C:\Users\ABC\Documents\PDF Image\*.pdf"))
    print(files)
    print(type(files))
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        executor.map(convertToImage,files)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

```py
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        executor.map(convertToImage,files)
```

These lines dont seem to work, it does not throw an error but the output is blank.

Comment: Why should these lines output anything? ``convertToImage`` does not print anything, and the result of ``executor.map`` is discarded.

Comment: This appears to be IO issue. instead of Process, Threads will help. You also break, in the first loop  as `i == 0`.  Last you are not capturing the answers back. you have to assign the pool to a variable.

Comment: By saying output is blank I meant the pdf are not converted, I don't see the images in the folder. @MisterMiyagi

Comment: @Prayson W. Daniel - thanks